# Making an image clickable for a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I have styled a simple dropdown menu using one of the Stack tutorials, but I want to move this dropdown menu away from the button and onto the logo image. So it works in the same way as the button but just triggered from the logo.

I can't figure out how to do this, or what bits of the below code to change so that the image is the trigger and can delete the button. Im sure it's a simple change but I cant sort it. Thank you!

The code I have for the button is below, and the image source url for the logo is: https://boys-cry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/bc_logo_black.png

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00000000;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

hr.solid {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <hr class="solid">
    <a href="#">WE</a>
    <hr class="solid">
    <a href="#">CLIENTS</a>
    <hr class="solid">
    <a href="mailto:info@boys-cry.com">GET IN TOUCH</a>
    <hr class="solid">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just put the image in the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

You really should resize the image to the exact size of your button

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
document.getElementById("drop").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
});


// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-content.show")
      .forEach(openDropdown => openDropdown.classList.remove('show'))
  }
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://boys-cry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/bc_logo_black.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 50px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00000000;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

hr.solid {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="drop" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <hr class="solid">
    <a href="#">WE</a>
    <hr class="solid">
    <a href="#">CLIENTS</a>
    <hr class="solid">
    <a href="mailto:info@boys-cry.com">GET IN TOUCH</a>
    <hr class="solid">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it's looking much better and works nicely. See the live page here: https://boys-cry.com/ however, I can't figure out how to style the button after clicking on it - when you click the logo and move the mouse away it creates a box and is pink - what do I need to add please so style it like the default view? Whats the css line to add for clicking it to change? thanks again!

Comment: Nevermind, found it. For anyone else - its the .dropbtn:focus line to add. thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @mplungjan - wondering if you could help with one more line that I cant figure out. Once the button is clicked and the menu drops down, there are 3 options. When I click each option I will have a popup of text display - that bit I can do fine, but what I cant see how to do is to make that dropdown menu stay open when one of the 3 links is clicked. Each link opens a popup on the same page so theres no navigation, but the menu disappears when one link is clicked, but I'd like the menu to stay open after a link is clicked. Thank you!